# Problem with checking to verify that I can write a file

Tags: lua

I am trying to write information to a file and I am having an issue with an if statement that verifies I have permission to write the file.

Specifically, I have tried to do this with  an if statement, but this ends up generating an error.  Here is the snippet of code that I am having issues with. The line with "trigger.action... acts like a print statement in the program environment I am using this script.  If I comment out the if statement, everything works fine.  But with the if statement, I get an error.

```
local function Write_Mission_Stats ()

 trigger.action.outTextForCoalition(2,MSG_Header .. "TEST - Simple test to write to file    TEST" .. MSG_Footer, 15)
--  Test_File_Handle = io.open("C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Saved Games\\DCS.openbeta\\AKA_Test_File.txt","w") 
 if io.open("C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Saved Games\\DCS.openbeta\\AKA_Test_File.txt","w") ~= nil then
   local Generate_Mission_Config_Report_Tbl_Outstring = Mission_Config_Report_Tbl ()
   Test_File_Handle = io.open("C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Saved Games\\DCS.openbeta\\AKA_Test_File.txt","w")
   Test_File_Handle:write("===========================\n")
   Test_File_Handle:write("Mission Stats for AKA Campaign\n")
   Test_File_Handle:write("===============================\n")
   Test_File_Handle:write(Generate_Mission_Config_Report_Tbl_Outstring)
 else
   trigger.action.outTextForCoalition(2, "\n*************************************\n\nNot able to open wirte file. \n\n**********************", 15)
 end
end
```

The error message is that the line with "    Test_File_Handle:write("===========================\n")" attempt to index global Test_Handle(a nil) value).  I check after the error and a file named "AKA_Test_File.txt" has been created,but is empty.

I tried adding "Test_File_Handle = io.open("C:\Users\Nathan\Saved Games\DCS.openbeta\AKA_Test_File.txt","w")" as the text condition to the if statement, but it didn't like that at all.

Can any tell me why this is happening, or a better way to check and see if I can write a file and not generate an error that stops the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a possible [time-of-check to time-of-use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) issue, or a filesystem resource issue given you are opening the file twice in rapid succession for writing. Either way the second call to `io.open` is *failing*, which goes unchecked, and `Test_File_Handle` is assigned `nil`.

Don't attempt to open the file twice. Open the file once, and store the resulting file handle in a variable immediately. `io.open` also returns an error message upon failure, so capture that as well.

Don't forget to close your files.

Try following this outline:

```lua
local function Write_Mission_Stats()
    local file, err = io.open(FILENAME, "w")

    if not file then
        -- failed to open file, let's display the error
        print(err) -- or error(err), or whatever debugging function
    else
        -- opened the file, write some data
        file:write("=============")  
        -- ...
        -- ...
        file:write(Mission_Config_Report_Tbl())
        file:close()
    end
end
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, at least I have tested and confirmed it will write the file.  All I need to do now is to test the case where I can't write the file

Thanks again for the help.  I am new to p[rogrmaing and didn't even know that TOCTOU was an issue.  Thanks for the link as well.